# Unable to display mesh on canvas using babylon js

Tags: javascript, babylonjs

I an a naive. I am referring to the video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvRa4uIW6Pk&t=0s
But in very first example, I am unable to display any mesh
I have copied the same code as in the video.
The code is as follows:

```
<html><head>
<title>

</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="http://www.babylonjs.com/babylon.js"></script>

<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("can");
    var engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true);
    var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
    var camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("cam", 0, Math.PI / 2, 10, BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0), scene);

    var light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight("hemo", new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0), scene);
    var box = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateBox("box", 3, scene);
    var material = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("nut", scene);

    box.material = material;
    material.diffuseColor = BABYLON.Color3.Red();


    engine.runRenderLoop(function () {
        box.rotation.y += 0.01;
        scene.render();
    });
</script>
<style>
    html,body{
        overflow:hidden;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
</style></head><body>    <canvas id="can" style="width:100%;height:100%"></canvas></body></html>
```

But in output It shows nothing.
https://s4.postimg.org/rmb9w24vh/New_Bitmap_Image_2.jpg

I am using web app in Visual studio 2015
Please help.

Comment: Do you have any error in the console?

Comment: Sir, it is showing WebGL not supported. But i am able to work on sandbox in same browser.

Comment: I think this is because you are using it locally (double click on the file) and not hosting it on a local webserver.